# How to test an IAP using a sandbox account on Apple Watch

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, watchos

I'm trying to test the purchase and restore code I've written for an IAP for an Apple Watch app.  In the iOS world I would make sure my device was logged in to a sandbox account under the sandbox section of Settings and then I could test an IOS IAP.  I'm trying to do the same for a watchOS app and getting an error.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: Apple Watch IAP purchase error]

The phone my watch is paired with is logged into a sandbox account (in the sandbox section of Settings).

Is the error implying that I need to be logged in on my phone using the sandbox account as the regular iCloud account?  Something else?  Has anyone successfully tested an IAP purchase on Apple Watch, and if so were there any special steps you needed to take to use a sandbox account?

I'd appreciate any tips and tricks.  Thanks!

Russ

Comment: Did you managed to solve the issue? I am bumping into the same message

Comment: Never did.  Pretty sure I ran into some documentation saying that Sandbox accounts are not supported on the watch.  The only way I was able to test this was to go through TestFlight and test out purchasing for real, reimbursing my testers. :(